# How to proxy subdomain to maindomain in nginx for SEO

Tags: nginx, proxy, seo, subdomain

I'm using a IDX data service which provide me a subdomain `search.mysite.com` to show search results and it is not a real `subdomain` since I don't have access on their backend, but only can add it on DNS.
However, it breaks Google SEO sitelinks. I've ranked the `www.masterdomain.com` to the TOP1 in Google search result, but since most of the nav links are not `/pages`, but `https://search.mysite.com/pages`, Google just doesn't recognize them as my sitelinks.

So here comes my question:
How can I proxy the subdomain(on other physical server) to `www.masterdomain.com` in nginx.

For example,

> search.mysite.com/pages -> [www.mysite.com/search/pages](http://www.mysite.com/search/pages).

So that I will be able to write `/pages` in nav links which Google might recognize them as my sitelinks.

I've tried `proxy_pass` and `return 301 subdomain`, they don't come out with what I expected.

Anything helps are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `proxy_pass` use `return 301 <http://path-to-website>`

```
server {
  root /var/www/html;

  server_name _;

  location / {
    return 301 https://www.master-domain.com/$uri;
  }
}
```